# How do I get a image link as input and make it appear on the view component below?

Tags: react-native

```
class Newsfeed extends React.Component{
    state = {
      text: ''
  };
   render(){
    return (
       <View>

      <Text style={{fontSize: 50}}>Junior Facebook</Text>
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: "column"}} />
      <View style={{top: 20, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 180, backgroundColor: "lightblue"}}>
      <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 150,
            borderStyle: "solid",
            borderWidth: 2,
            fontSize: 30
          }}
          placeholder="New Post"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ backgroundColor: "green", marginLeft: 220, width: 80, height: 40 }}
        >
          <Text style={{fontSize: 24}}>Enter</Text>

        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>

      <View style={{marginTop: 30, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 180, backgroundColor: "pink"}} >
      <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 65, height: 45, marginLeft: 260}}><Text>Share</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 65, height: 45, marginLeft: 220, marginTop: -45}}><Text>Like</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View style={{marginTop: 10, marginLeft: 0, width: 300, height: 130, backgroundColor: "yellow"}} >

      </View>
    </View>
  ) 
  }
}
```

The above is my current code. When I type in an image link in TextInput, I want the image to appear on the yellow View Component below. I have tried many different ways but it still does not work. How can I do so?

Thank you

Comment: react-native has an Image component that you pass your url to the source prop. https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#source

Comment: Could you elaborate with code please?

Comment: There is an example on that link.

Comment: Start by trying to render the same image in their example. Once you have an Image rendering then you need a way to save your text input to state. Then you can use the text input as a prop for the Image component.

Comment: I dont get it though....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@高鵬翔 answer is perfect, but said that you want to display image after clicking on 'enter' button. So here is my solution :

```js
...
...
import { View, Text, Image } from "react-native";
...
...

//state 
this.state = {
  link: "",
  enteredImageUri: "",
};

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      ...
      ...
      <View
        style={{
          top: 20,
          marginLeft: 0,
          width: 300,
          height: 180,
          backgroundColor: "lightblue",
        }}
      >
        <TextInput
          style={{
            height: 150,
            borderStyle: "solid",
            borderWidth: 2,
            fontSize: 30,
          }}
          placeholder="New Post"
          value={this.state.link}
          onChangeText={(link) => this.setState({ link })}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "green",
            marginLeft: 220,
            width: 80,
            height: 40,
          }}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              enteredImageUri: this.state.link,
            });
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 24 }}>Enter</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <View>
        {/* Image View */}
        {this.state.enteredImageUri === "" ? (
          <Text>No Image link entered</Text>
        ) : (
          <Image
            source={{ uri: this.state.enteredImageUri }}
            style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
      ...
      ...
    </View>
  );
}
```

As you can see I have just assigned textinput text into the another state variable `enteredImageUri`, which will be used to display image.

Comment: So, have I need to post this answer there @高鵬翔?

Comment: It's ok, I think he get what he want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Image Tag](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images#network-images) to show image.

Like this:

```js
import {Image} from 'react-native';

...
<Image source={{uri: 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

And you have to store the text input as a state to control Image as @Will said.
So you have to add a state and the text input should like this:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: '' };
}
<TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
```

And see how you want to control Image view to show something like this, but this may be error if the uri haven't finish?  Based on when you pass the correct uri to let it show, but it's an another question:

```js
import {Image} from 'react-native';

...
<Image source={{uri: this.state.text}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />
```

Comment: I did that and when I typed in a link and clicked button, nothing shows up in the yellow view

Comment: It works but I want my image to appear when I click the "Enter" button

Comment: Can you help me out?

Comment: I can give you some advance direct to achieve the effect, but if you want something full code, this place is not suitable because of the edition rules. You could [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (It solved) and create a new question to ask.

Comment: If I want to achieve this effect, I will create a new state something like `uriForPic`, when I push the button, `setState` the text to this state and read it to image source `this.state.uriForPic`to achieve that effect.